# Having issues with my PC, randomly turns off and on. No signal on monitor sometimes

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors

I have a PC with this configuration:

- **Processor:** Intel Core i5 9400F (No VGA),
- **MB:** MSI B360M PRO-VH,
- **Graphics:** MSI GTX 1050ti 4GB OCV1,
- **RAM:** G.SKILL 16GB 2400BUS x1,
- **SSD:** Transcend 512GB M.2 SSD,
- **HDD:** Old 1TB HDD from my damaged laptop,
- **PSU:** Thermaltake Litepower 650W,
- **Monitor:** HP 22fw (1920x1080), connected via HDMI.

Currently, I am running with Windows 10

- **Version:** 2004
- **OS build:** 21301.1010.

I am using this build from March 2019, more than two years and current Windows is installed over a year. For last four months I am using an additional LG 18.5inch(1366x768) monitor via DVI-D port with a DVI-D to VGA converter.

**Here is the issue:**

From yesterday, sometimes it's going off without any signal or warning and starts on its own, without no major load. And sometimes it has no signal after turning on, but it's on as I hear startup sound.

Then I monitored, CPU and GPU temperature is pretty normal. This 'no signal' also sometimes happens when I manually start or restart the machine. In this state, I disconnected and reconnected monitor cables, but that didn't work.

Occasionally, I use my android phone as an additional monitor via Spacedesk software. And, I've seen that, when monitors are not getting signal, Spacedesk is on and I can use my PC on my mobile screen.

So, what is the issue? Any software/driver related problem? Is it the graphics card or any other components?

Comment: So, to clarify, your screen goes off and on by itself, and when it comes back on, you can continue to work in Windows? Its not a reboot? It could be an issue with the DVI-D to VGA adapter.

Comment: No, not the screen. My pc goes off instantly and starts normally like after pressing the on button. And after log in, my previous running application unsaved works gone, which does not happen when manually reboot or shutting down and on. It's the first issue.

Comment: And the second issue is, sometimes after starting no signal in my monitors, in any. But I hear startup sound. Then after restarting one/two/three times its normal.

Comment: If your pc restarts, then a BSoD has occured. Refer to the eventlog to find out what the STOP code is, and research that in order to fix your issue.

Comment: Sounds good. But I don't know how to get that eventlog you are saying about. Can you please tell me how to find ?

Comment: Rightclick your startmenu button, choose eventlog. If your OS is not english, translate it to your language first.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, far this seems a kernel related issue.

Comment: Troubleshooting a BSoD is tricky. If you have a minidump, you can analyse that, but you also have a stopcode. Creating a new question and posting that you experience BSoD's and what the stopcode is may get you the help you need.